# Null Object Reference ao abrir um Dialog Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-activity

Esta dando erro ao abrir um **Dialog Fragment** em uma **outra Activity** utilizando um **método**.

**ERRO:**

> 07-06 11:21:25.145 18783-18783/com.vuforia.samples.Books
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              Process: com.vuforia.samples.Books, PID: 18783
>                                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   com.vuforia.samples.Books.ui.ActivityFragmentList.GPSFragmentActivity.exibirGPSFragmentDialog()'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                  at
>   com.vuforia.samples.Books.ui.ActivityList.AboutScreen$1.onClick(AboutScreen.java:51)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5723)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22689)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6364)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)

**GPSFragmentActivity.java**

```
package com.vuforia.samples.Books.ui.ActivityFragmentList;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.vuforia.samples.Books.R;
import com.vuforia.samples.Books.ui.ActivityList.AboutScreen;

/**
 * Created by th on 05/07/17.
 */

public class GPSFragmentActivity extends DialogFragment {

    private TextView tvShoppingNome;
    private TextView tvShoppingLicenseKey;
    private TextView tvShoppingAccessKey;
    private TextView tvShoppingSecretKey;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        // Cria o objeto para configurar o AlertDialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        // Define o Layout do AlertDialog
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gps_fragment, null);
        builder.setView(dialogView);

        // Define o Layout Personalizado do AlertDialog
        builder.setTitle("GEOLOCALIZAÇÃO");

        /*tvShoppingNome = (TextView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.txtShoppingNome);
        tvShoppingLicenseKey = (TextView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.txtShoppingLicenseKey);
        tvShoppingAccessKey = (TextView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.txtShoppingAccessKey);
        tvShoppingSecretKey = (TextView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.txtShoppingSecretKey);*/

        builder.setNegativeButton("LOCALIZAR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Fecha o AlertDialog
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        builder.setPositiveButton("CONFIRMAR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });

        // Cria o Objeto AlertDialog
        return builder.create();
    }

    public void exibirGPSFragmentDialog(){
        DialogFragment gpsFragmentDialog = new GPSFragmentActivity();
        gpsFragmentDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "gpsFragmentDialog");
    }
}
```

**AboutScreen.java**

```
    package com.vuforia.samples.Books.ui.ActivityList;


    import com.vuforia.samples.Books.R;
    import com.vuforia.samples.Books.ui.ActivityFragmentList.GPSFragmentActivity;

    import android.os.Bundle;;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    ;


    public class AboutScreen extends FragmentActivity {

        // Classes
        private GPSFragmentActivity gpsFragmentActivity;

        // Botões
        private Button btnLocalizar;

        private String mClassToLaunch;
        private String mClassToLaunchPackage;


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.about_screen);

            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            mClassToLaunchPackage = getPackageName();
            mClassToLaunch = mClassToLaunchPackage + "." + extras.getString("ACTIVITY_TO_LAUNCH");

gpsFragmentActivity = new GPSFragmentActivity();

            // Botão Localizar
            this.btnLocalizar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Localizar);
            this.btnLocalizar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    gpsFragmentActivity.exibirGPSFragmentDialog();

                }
            });


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você não inicializou o objeto `GPSFragmentActivity gpsFragmentActivity` em lugar nenhum do código da classe AboutScreen.

Comment: Eu já tentei fazer gpsFragmentActivity = new GPSFragmentActivity(); e ele dá: android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.beginTransaction()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

Contornei o erro da seguinte maneira:

**1)** Retirei a função exibirGPSFragmentDialog() da Class GPSFragmentActivity

**2)** Inseri essa função na MainActivity (AboutScreen) da seguinte maneira:

```
public void exibirGPSFragmentDialog(){
    GPSFragmentActivity gpsFragmentDialog = new GPSFragmentActivity();
    gpsFragmentDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "gpsFragmentDialog");
}
```

**3)** Depois alterei no click do Botão da seguinte maneira:

```
// Botão Localizar
this.btnLocalizar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Localizar);
this.btnLocalizar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        exibirGPSFragmentDialog();

    }
});
```